# Accessing data from an instantiated user control in a tabpage?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a form with a button that replicates the contents (user controls) of the 2nd tab using a user control (ie: adding a new set of text boxes, like Address 2, 3 and so on). So far, I've been able to add a tab page and instantiate the user control on the newly created tab page but I don't know how I can access the data from each newly instantiated tab page with the user control. I'm thinking that I need to declare each newly instantiated instance of DetailTab (the class containing the Details user control), but I'm not really sure. I'm not a programmer by profession, so an elementary kind of explanation would be truly appreciated.

```
Public Class KMCProfile 'Class with the actual UI
  Private Sub AddDetails_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddDetails.Click
      KMC.TabPages.Add(New DetailTab)
      KMC.TabPages(tabCount).Name = "KMCDetails" & tabCount
      KMC.TabPages(tabCount).Text = "KMC Details (" & tabCount & ")"
      KMC.SelectedTab = KMC.TabPages(tabCount)
      tabCount += 1

      If tabCount = 5 Then
          AddDetails.Enabled = False
      End If
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class DetailTab
    Inherits TabPage

    Public Sub New()
        Controls.Add(New Details)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Details ' The User Control Class
  Public Property ISO1 as String
  ...
  Public Property ISO40 as String

  Public Sub FetchData()
    ISO1 = txtISO1.text
    ...
    ISO40 = txtISO40.text
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not really sure if a specific tab contains your usercontrol or not, then you could query the Controls collection and ask to return al the controls of type Details

```
 Dim current = KMC.TabPages(pageIndex).Controls.OfType(Of Details)().FirstOrDefault()
 if current IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim text = current.ISO1
      .. get the other properties here 
 End If
```

The instance of the user controls are kept in the Controls collection of the tabpage, so you retrieve the instance that you have added querying the TabPage(x) controls collection.

Of course if you need to identify the user control that you are handling then some kind of properties in the user control itself could be added (or just use the user control name)

```
 if current.Name = "KMCDetails1" Then 
     .....
```

Comment: It's not really in each of the Tab Pages, think of it this way: Tab 2 contains the Address 1 fields. If the user presses the Add Address button, it adds a new tab page with the user controls. In reality, it's not that simple as there are 40 controls where I need to get data from in the user control. Is there anyway that I can get the values of the properties from the instantiated user control? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I see, then the page could contain one of your user control or not. The problem could be solved using the OfType extension https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx